# Trying to run scheduled code in background of flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a app where a requirement is to run a piece of code periodically every half hr. The app(apk) file will not be deployed to app store. It will be used on phones locally on a few users.
The app acts as a proxy server for https requests. App is developed using flutter.

My requirement is to pull data from AWS every 30 minutes and forward requests to another system as proxy and get a response.
My question is how can this be achieved when user has the app closed and app acts as a proxy in background without user involvement.

I am new to app development and looking for suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of task do you want to perform with every half-hour cron?

Comment: API call to lambda in AWS to fetch data required in app

Comment: I don't understand here actually, what do you mean by fetching data, I mean what I get is that you've to fetch data and update your database maybe? Like I've worked on an app, where we've data stored in Firestore and need to update data every half hour, so we use Cloud Schedule & Functions to update data in firebase. I really don't get here why would you fetch data even when the app is closed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.